# Manually raising a property change for an observable list to refresh

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

```
    private static ObservableCollection<Contact> _contacts;
    public ObservableCollection<Contact> Contacts
    {
        get { return _contacts; }
        set
        {
            _contacts = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Contacts");
        }
    }
```

This observable gets passed to another view model where basic operations are implemented.

```
    public async void OnSave()
    {
        Contacts.Add(Contact);
        Contacts = Utility.ArrangeContacts(Contacts);

         await Navigation.PopAsync();            
    }
```

I can see that the new contact is added in the list however the list is still not arranged properly. Do I need to trigger the OnProperty Change manually for the Observable list to refresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what it is you're trying to do. But from the code I gather that you update the list somewhere else.

From what I see is that you reset the `Contacts` reference to a new `ObservableList`. That breaks your data-binding causing the not updating of your UI probably.

Retrieve the new list, clear your current `ObservableCollection` and repopulate it. Or, set your `DataBinding` property again, but that will cause all bindings to be evaluated again.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to Xamarin. Yes I'm passing the ObservableList to another view model. The original observable list is static so im assuming im still referencing to that? I can see that the new contact is added to the original observable list property but not arranged.

Comment: Found the problem in my Arrange Contacts Im returning a new instance of Observable. Sorry for wasting your time :)

Comment: That is what I meant to say :) No problem, glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

from my custom `public class NiftyObservableCollection<T> : ObservableRangeCollection<T>`

```
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void ReportItemChange(T item)
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    {
        NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args =
            new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(
                NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace,
                item,
                item,
                IndexOf(item));
        OnCollectionChanged(args);
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void RefreshRange(int index, IEnumerable<T> collection)
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    {
        CheckReentrancy();
        var changedItems = collection is List<T> ? (List<T>)collection : new List<T>(collection);

        for (var currentIndex = index; currentIndex < changedItems.Count+index; currentIndex++ )
        {
            try
            {
                var i = changedItems[currentIndex];
                Items.RemoveAt(currentIndex); //remove
                Items.Insert(currentIndex, i); //insert new 
            }
            catch
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        // OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item[]"));
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace, changedItems, changedItems, index));
    }
```